# What should the install tag mean

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice the `install` tag doesn't have a wiki, so I thought I would try to put one together. However, I'm not sure what it should be. It looks like most of the questions with the `install` tag refer to installing packages, usually from a repository, but there are also a number of questions about installing emacs from source or different repositories.

Should `install` cover all of this? Or should it be split into `package-install` and `emacs-install`? The `package-install` aspect of this may already be covered by the `package` tag, and the `build` tag exists for building emacs from source, so maybe we can get rid of `install` altogether?

Comment: If there are not lots of uses so far, and we don't expect lots, then let's leave it, i.e., let it cover both. If there are already lots or we expect lots, it could be split into `package-install` and `install` (for Emacs, the name of this SE site).